# Removing unnecessary string after grabbing a website link.- Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, roblox

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow so I apologize for any mistakes I made.

I want to remove unnecessary words after yoinking a link from a different channel.

Code so far:

```
    message.content = message.content.toLowerCase();
    let checker = 'roblox.com/games/59'
    if(message.content.search(checker) >= 8){
        let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("**Possible condo found!**")
        .setColor(randomColor)
        .setDescription("Grabbed: "+ message.content +"")
        client.channels.get("809420315230339112").send({ embed: embed })
    }
```

This is the output after grabbing a link.

```
Grabbed: https://www.roblox.com/games/5924680090/chromosome-ss-Place this my game it cool
```

I want to remove the following string so it only leaves the link present.

```
this my game it cool
```

Ideas?

Comment: A simple solution would be to split the string in `message.content` and slice and keep only the first item. You could even use Array.shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use regex for this and check if there is a string that looks like a URL. The regex `(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)` checks if a string contains `http`, `https`, `www` and using the [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method you can grab all these matched strings into an array.

Try the snippet below:

```js
const content = "Oh, https://roblox.com/games/5924680090/chromosome-ss-Place this my game it cool. Another cool link: https://stackoverflow.com :)"

const urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/gi
const urls = content.match(urlRegex)
const robloxLink = urls && urls[0]

console.log({ urls, robloxLink })
```

You could also move it to its own function and use it like this:

```js
function findLinks(string) {
  const urlRegex = /(((https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/gi
  return content.match(urlRegex)
}

const content = "Oh, https://roblox.com/games/5924680090/chromosome-ss-Place this my game it cool. Another cool link: https://stackoverflow.com :)"

console.log(findLinks(content))
```

Or, you can use an npm package like [`get-urls`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-urls).

Answer (score 0):

This example **separates** the `string` at **each space** and creates an `array` from it. Then `.slice()` removes **all but the first** `element`.

```js
const grabbedLink = " https://www.roblox.com/games/5924680090/chromosome-ss-Place this my game it cool"

const onlyLink = grabbedLink.trim().split(' ').slice(0, 1);

console.log(onlyLink);
```

---

### References:

- [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: What if the text is infront of the link Ex. 

this my game it cool https://www.roblox.com/games/5924680090/chromosome-ss-Place

Comment: @systemGene In this case you can use [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim). I updated my answer and added a space infront of the link and with `.trim()` it works